# Undefined method error on signup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters

I have a table 'Users' with various columns. One of those columns was username. I decided to remove the column with a migration. After doing so, I tried to create a new User via a signup form (create action) but am getting an undefined method error for username and I'm not sure why. The error is being thrown on @user.save.

Here is the relevant code, first the users controller's actions, and then the actual form being submitted.

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
end

def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  if @user.save
    session[:user_id] = @user.id
    redirect_to @user, notice: 'Thank you for registering!'
  else
    render :new 
  end
end

<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <%= render "shared/errors", object: @user %>
  <fieldset>
    <ol>
      <li class="required">
        <%= f.label :name %>
        <%= f.text_field :name, size: 40, autofocus: true %>
      </li>
      <li class="required">
        <%= f.label :email %>
        <%= f.email_field :email, size: 40 %>
      </li>
      <li class="required">
        <%= f.label :password %>
        <%= f.password_field :password, size: 40 %>
      </li>
      <li class="required">
        <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirm Password" %>
        <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, size: 40 %>
      </li>
    </ol>
    <p>
      <% if @user.new_record? %>
        <%= f.submit "Create Account" %>
      <% else %>
        <%= f.submit "Update Account" %>
      <% end %>
    </p>
  </fieldset>
<% end %>
```

Any thoughts? Stack trace, as requested:

activemodel (4.0.5) lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:439:in `method_missing'
activerecord (4.0.5) lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:167:in`method_missing'
activemodel (4.0.5) lib/active_model/validator.rb:151:in `block in validate'
activemodel (4.0.5) lib/active_model/validator.rb:150:in`each'
activemodel (4.0.5) lib/active_model/validator.rb:150:in `validate'
activerecord (4.0.5) lib/active_record/validations/presence.rb:5:in`validate'
activesupport (4.0.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:283:in `_callback_before_609'
activesupport (4.0.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:447:in`_run__3888567514204995588__validate__callbacks'
activesupport (4.0.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
activemodel (4.0.5) lib/active_model/validations.rb:373:in`run_validations!'
activemodel (4.0.5) lib/active_model/validations/callbacks.rb:106:in `block in run_validations!'
activesupport (4.0.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in`_run__3888567514204995588__validation__callbacks'
activesupport (4.0.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
activemodel (4.0.5) lib/active_model/validations/callbacks.rb:106:in`run_validations!'
activemodel (4.0.5) lib/active_model/validations.rb:314:in `valid?'
activerecord (4.0.5) lib/active_record/validations.rb:70:in`valid?'
activerecord (4.0.5) lib/active_record/validations.rb:77:in `perform_validations'
activerecord (4.0.5) lib/active_record/validations.rb:51:in`save'
activerecord (4.0.5) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:32:in `save'
activerecord (4.0.5) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:270:in`block (2 levels) in save'
activerecord (4.0.5) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:330:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
activerecord (4.0.5) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in`block in transaction'
activerecord (4.0.5) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:221:in `within_new_transaction'
activerecord (4.0.5) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in`transaction'
activerecord (4.0.5) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:209:in `transaction'
activerecord (4.0.5) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:327:in`with_transaction_returning_status'
activerecord (4.0.5) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:270:in `block in save'
activerecord (4.0.5) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:285:in`rollback_active_record_state!'
activerecord (4.0.5) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:269:in `save'
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:17:in`create'
actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.0.5) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in`process_action'
actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.5) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in`block in process_action'
activesupport (4.0.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:403:in `_run__2040789553997201778__process_action__callbacks'
activesupport (4.0.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in`run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.0.5) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in`process_action'
actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.0.5) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in`block in instrument'
activesupport (4.0.5) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.0.5) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in`instrument'
actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in`process_action'
activerecord (4.0.5) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.5) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in`process'
actionpack (4.0.5) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:44:in `process'
actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in`dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in`block in action'
actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in`dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in`block in call'
actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in`call'
actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:674:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in`call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in`call'
actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:241:in`call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in`call'
actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:486:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.5) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in`call'
activerecord (4.0.5) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.5) lib/active_record/migration.rb:373:in`call'
actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.0.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in`_run__1209442307347215813__call__callbacks'
activesupport (4.0.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in`call'
actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:64:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in`call'
actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in`call'
railties (4.0.5) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.0.5) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in`block in call'
activesupport (4.0.5) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.0.5) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in`tagged'
activesupport (4.0.5) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.0.5) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in`call'
actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in`call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (4.0.5) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in`call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in`call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
railties (4.0.5) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in`call'
railties (4.0.5) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in`call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in`service'

Comment: Post the stack trace, it will tell you where the error is happening.

Comment: Stack trace edited in post above.

Comment: The whole stack trace, not just one line of it.  The information is in there somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the stack trace, it tells you what's wrong.  Take a peek in your `User` class.  Maybe you have something like:

```
validates_presence_of :username
```

or

```
validates :username, presence: true
```

Comment: This is the first time I've taken a look at it. Thanks for pointing out its usefulness. I see it throwing a bunch of validation notices, so I can see why checking the model would be the next logical step. Low and behold something was hidden away in the model. Thanks.

Comment: No problem.  The stack trace is generated the moment something throws an exception.  It may not be the first line, as the "source" of the exception, but it should be in there somewhere.  Sometimes it's a bit of a game to get the information out.